# Importing a function and assigning it to a variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I'm practising with unit test module.

I have this simple code. It is a function that joins strings so that I can get this result: "City, Country"

```
def city_country(city_name, country_name):

    """Simple code that prints City, Country"""

    print(city_name.title() + ", " country_name.title())
```

When I run it, the function works OK.

I wrote a class to test the code with unit tests, and I got an error.

I noticed that when I assign the function to a variable, like this :

```
city_country_var = city_country('Punto Fijo', 'Venezuela')
```

And then import it to the TestClass(or somewhere else), print it, this is the result :

```
Punto Fijo, Venezuela 
None
```

I don't know how to handle it or why is it caused, since it's the same function that worked fine earlier by itself. But it only gives me that result if I import the function to another file. Can I get some advice about why does it happen and how to solve it?

Comment: `print` is not the same as `return`

Comment: Yes, I'm going to re-read in order to understand it better! Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your `city_country` function does not `return` any value. It just prints the result and returns `None` (by default).

Apply those changes and your variable should have the string value you desire:

```
def city_country(city_name, country_name):

    """Simple code that prints City, Country"""
    result = (city_name.title() + ", " country_name.title())
    print(result)
    return result
```

Comment: Thank you so much!. Now that you mention it, I just noticed that i have never used return, I'm going to start reading even more about it in order to improve myself. Thanks again!